# Yii 1, отправка POST

Tags: php, yii, post

добрый день! Есть сайт на Yii-1, нужно при вызове определенного метода createLinck сделать отправку POST-данных на другой сайт, при этом формы нет, все данные уже готовы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте curl и метод `POST`.

Есть extension для yii [yii-curl](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-curl/), использовать так:

```
$output = Yii::app()->curl->post($url, $data);
```

Или же нативный php curl.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!